# Actions class in Selenium webdriver does not work in Firefox 14

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver for C# with Firefox 14

I am trying to right click on the link, but it fails with an error:
`OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException : Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.`

This was working in Firefox 13. 
Please let me know if anyone has a workaround.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
         IWebElement tagElement = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("FolderA"));
        //right click on FolderA            
         builder.MoveToElement(tagElement).Perform();
builder.ContextClick(tagElement).Perform();
```

Comment: As JimEvans has pointed out, ensure you run the latest version of Selenium, have a check of their Google Code project and take a peek at their commits to see if FF support has changed in recent versions. If not, file a bug off to Selenium guys. Downgrade to FF 13 in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Selenium WebDriver are you using? Remember that a new version of Firefox often requires a new version of WebDriver for native events because of changes to the Firefox native code interfaces between browser versions. Native event support for Firefox 14, for example wasn't added to WebDriver until 2.25.0.

Comment: how about safari and chrome on MacOSx?